# How to separate a 3D Plot with a gap

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am interested in the plot of the 3 hump function $f(x)= 2x^2 - 1.05x^4 +\frac{x^6}{6}+xy+y^2$ , for $x,y\in[-2,2]$.

So in order to show the  **3 humps** of the respective plot I gave the following three inputs like this:

```
p = Show[Plot3D[2 x^2-1.05 x^4+x^6/6+x y+y^2,{x,-2,2.2},{y,-1/5,1/5},PlotRange->All,AxesLabel->Automatic,Mesh->5,PlotLabel->" z=2 x^2-1.05 x^4+x^6/6+x y+y^2 (Three-Hump Camel function) ",PlotTheme->"Web",BoundaryStyle->Directive[Black,Thick]],ListPointPlot3D[{{0,0,0}}->{"{0, 0, 0}"},LabelingFunction->Bottom]]
s = Plot3D[z=0.6,{x,-2,2},{y,-1/5,1/5},AxesLabel->{x,y,z},Mesh->3,ColorFunctionScaling->True,ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap"]
Show[p,s]
```

But I am not so happy with that. I would like my final Plot to look like an object cut in three pieces by an invisible knife and these pieces are separated a small distance from each other. Can you advise me how to do that? Thanks

Comment: maybe something like `Plot3D[2 x^2 - 1.05 x^4 + x^6/6 + x y + y^2, {x, -2, 2.2}, {y, -1/5, 
  1/5}, PlotRange -> All, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0.6}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Dashed, White], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html):

```
Plot3D[2 x^2 - 1.05 x^4 + x^6/6 + x y + y^2, {x, -2, 2.2}, {y, -1/5, 1/5},
 PlotRange -> All, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0.6}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, White], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

To add additional mesh lines as in OP you can use multiple mesh functions:

```
Plot3D[2 x^2 - 1.05 x^4 + x^6/6 + x y + y^2, {x, -2, 2.2}, {y, -1/5, 1/5}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0.6}, 3}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thin, White], Gray}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a combination of options [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) and [`ExclusionsStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html):

```
Plot3D[2 x^2 - 1.05 x^4 + x^6/6 + x y + y^2, {x, -2, 2.2}, {y, -1/5, 1/5}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> {2 x^2 - 1.05 x^4 + x^6/6 + x y + y^2 == .6}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Thin, White], 
 Mesh -> 3, 
 PlotTheme -> "Web", 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]